# invalid GraphQL introspection query result

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

After modifying my appsync schema on aws console, I am trying to run the 'amplify codegen' cli command in order to update my local project files. However, I obtain the following error:

```
amplify codegen
- Downloading the introspection schema
√ Downloaded the schema
- Generating GraphQL operations
- Generating
undefined
√ Code generated successfully and saved in file
2018-10-29T10:48:28.717Z - error: uncaughtException: GraphQL schema file should contain a valid GraphQL introspection query result date=Mon Oct 29 2018 18:48:28 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time), pid=4768, uid=null, gid=null, cwd=C:\code_repo\dir\a\react-dashboard, execPath=C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe, version=v8.10.0, argv=[C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe, C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\bin\amplify, codegen], rss=126963712, heapTotal=103223296, heapUsed=79488616, external=390282, loadavg=[0, 0, 0], uptime=1068500.4532678, trace=[column=11, file=C:\Users\kaustavg\amplify-launch\amplify-cli\packages\amplify-graphql-docs-generator\src\generator\generate.ts, function=Object.generate [as default], line=19, method=generate [as default], native=false, column=57, file=C:\Users\kaustavg\amplify-launch\amplify-cli\packages\amplify-graphql-docs-generator\src\index.ts, function=generate, line=43, method=null, native=false, column=11, file=C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.10.0\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\amplify-codegen\src\commands\statements.js, function=projects.forEach, line=35, method=forEach, native=false, column=null, file=null, function=Array.forEach, line=null, method=forEach, native=false, column=12, file=C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.10.0\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\amplify-codegen\src\commands\statements.js, function=generateStatements, line=17, method=null, native=false, column=9, file=C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.10.0\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\amplify-codegen\src\commands\generateStatementsAndType.js, function=Object.generateStatementsAndTypes [as generate], line=27, method=generateStatementsAndTypes [as generate], native=false, column=null, file=null, function=null, line=null, method=null, native=false, column=7, file=internal/process/next_tick.js, function=process._tickDomainCallback, line=228, method=_tickDomainCallback, native=false], stack=[Error: GraphQL schema file should contain a valid GraphQL introspection query result,     at Object.generate [as default] (C:\Users\kaustavg\amplify-launch\amplify-cli\packages\amplify-graphql-docs-generator\src\generator\generate.ts:19:11),     at generate (C:\Users\kaustavg\amplify-launch\amplify-cli\packages\amplify-graphql-docs-generator\src\index.ts:43:57),     at projects.forEach (C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.10.0\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\amplify-codegen\src\commands\statements.js:35:11),     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>),     at generateStatements (C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.10.0\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\amplify-codegen\src\commands\statements.js:17:12),     at Object.generateStatementsAndTypes [as generate] (C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.10.0\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\amplify-codegen\src\commands\generateStatementsAndType.js:27:9),     at <anonymous>,     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)]
```

What is causing this to happen?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem when I was trying to move my project from one computer to another.

At first I thought it to be a memory error because it was error out during the generation process.

The thing that resolved the error for me was by installing the `GraphQL` package.

It turns out when installing the amplify package with npm, it would display the requirement for graphql, but it doesn't if you use yarn instead.